# How might I manage weighted operations via threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The following is a programming problem I am trying to solve...

I am creating a (C++ 11) server application that manages operations being performed on other servers.  Thus far, I have designed it to do the following:

- start a thread for each remote server (with operations on it that are being managed), that polls the server to make sure it's still there/working.
- start a thread for each operation that it is managing, that polls the remote server to get info about the current state of the operation.

Where I am running into issues is... The calls to the remote server to verify that it is there/working, and the calls to get the status of the operations being managed on the remote server are "waited" operations.  If something stops working (either a remote server stops responding, or I am not able to get the state of an operation running on a remote server, I WAS attempting to just "kill" the thread that monitors that server or operation, and flag it (the server or operation) as dead/non-responsive.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any clean way to kill a thread.

Note that I was trying to "kill" threads because many of the calls that I am performing are "waited" operations, and I can not have the application hang because it is waiting for completion of an operation (that in some cases may never complete).  I have done some research on ways to "kill" an active thread (stop it from a manager thread).  One of the only C++ thread management libraries that I could find that even supported a C++ method to "kill" a thread is the "ZThread" library, but using it's kill method doesn't seem to work consistently.

I need to find a way to start executing a segment of code (ie: a thread), that will be performing some waited operation, and kill execution of that code when needed (not wait for the operation to complete.

Suggestions???

Comment: Instead of killing the thread why not detach it?

Comment: Recommendation: Rather than polling the monitored operations and servers, have the operations and servers send a periodic keep-alive message. No message==something has gone wrong. Another recommendation: Rather than killing a thread, which can leave the program in a bad state, send a message to no longer wanted thread and instruct it to end itself cleanly. Save thread killing for rare occasions.

Comment: Look up message queues and intertask messages. Don't just wait, wait on an instruction. If a job never materializes, you can at least wake the thread with a terminate instruction and exit politely. If a thread has a loop where it can get stuck, peek at the message queue periodically in the loop to see if it contains a terminate instruction.